# Visual Studio Watch Window: viewing an integer as a series of flags

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm looking at a codebase with a certain way of formatting flags:

```
enum eFlags
{
    e_FirstFlag = 0,
    e_SecondFlag = 1,
    e_ThirdFlag = 2,
    e_FourthFlag = 3,
}
```

Where each flag's value represents the bit that should be flipped to turn that flag on. So `long myFlags = 9;` = 2^3 + 2^0 = `e_FourthFlag` and `e_FirstFlag` are flipped.

When I'm debugging this code, I do not care that `myFlags = 9`. Putting `myFlags,b` in the watch window to get `0b1001` is better, but I want the watch window to display `myFlags = e_FirstFlag | e_FourthFlag`. If I input `(eFlags)myFlags` in the watch window, it'll give `e_TenthFlag` if that exists (since that will = 9) or it'll just say `myFlags = 9`.

The watch window [can do my desired behavior if the enum values are powers of two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/03/10/visual-studio-2008-enum-bit-flags-visualization.aspx), but these enums are not powers of two, and I can't change them.

Is there any way to get this flag visualization?

Comment: Wow, today I discovered that you can do this: "Putting `myFlags,b` in the watch window to get 0b1001 is better". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible because of your enum values: if `myFlags` has value `3` then this could either be `e_SecondFlag | e_ThirdFlag` or `e_FourthFlag`, both will return `3`.

With powers of two you don't have this problem because every value can only be composed in one way.

You'll either have to switch to powers of two or stay satisfied with what you have.

```
void Main()
{
    var flags = Flags.FourthFlag;
    Console.WriteLine ((int) flags);

    flags = Flags.SecondFlag | Flags.ThirdFlag;
    Console.WriteLine ((int) flags);
}

enum Flags
{
    FirstFlag = 0,
    SecondFlag = 1,
    ThirdFlag = 2,
    FourthFlag = 3,
}
```

Output:

> 3
>   3

In fact, the article itself explains this already..

> This feature was specifically designed to visualize bit flag names that are a power of two. As soon as an enum contains members whose values don’t adhere to this requirement, the visualization won’t work since arbitrary numeric values (i.e. those not a power of 2) cannot be interpreted by the debugger in a single way.